# Доработать алгоритм (подскажите)

Tags: java, android, математика

В целях обучения пишу простой компас на AndroidStudio.

С датчиков получаю отклонение от севера в градусах, сглаживаю его значение, рисую вертикальную стрелку и поворачиваю ее на известное количество градусов. Сглаживаю по формуле `b=xb+(1-x)a`, b=сглаж. знач., а=знач. с датчика. x=коэф. сглаж. 0<=x<=1.

При переходе через 0 (например, 359>360>1) алгоритм сглаживания пересчитывает значение не резко, а плавно уменьшая. Стрелка отматывает круг назад. Соотв. при переходе 1>0>359>358 стрелка отматывает круг по часовой. Подкиньте идею, как сглаживать плавно и обходить этот 0 резко.

Answer (score 1):

x - текущий угол
y - показание датчика

при их несовпадении вычисляете два значения

af = max(x,y)-min(x,y);

ab = 360-max(x,y)+min(x,y);

r=abs(ab-af)/(ab-af)*abs(x-y)/(x-y);

Если r=-1, то против часовой, если r=1, то по часовой на min(ab,af) градусов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте превратить некоторый набор точек на циферблате в связанный циклический список (0,15,30,...345,360 градусов).
Далее, перед назначением позиции стрелки - смотреть длину пути. Какой путь по количеству нод списка меньше - по тому пути и отправлять стрелку.

UPD: Что можно сделать:

1. Создадим класс CheckPoint:

```
public class CheckPoint{
  private CheckPoint left;
  private CheckPoint right;
  private Integer value;

  public CheckPoint(){
    left  = null;
    right = null;
    value = null;
  }

  public CheckPoint(CheckPoint right){
    left  = null;
    this.right = right;
    value = null;
  }

  public CheckPoint(CheckPoint left,CheckPoint right){
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
    value = null;
  }

  public CheckPoint(Integer value, CheckPoint left,CheckPoint right){
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public CheckPoint(Integer value){
    this.left  = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public void setRight(CheckPoint right){
    this.right = right;
  }

  public void setLeft(CheckPoint left){
    this.left = left;
  }

  public void setValue(Integer value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public CheckPoint getLeft(){return this.left;}

  public CheckPoint getRight(){return this.right;}

  public Integer getValue(){return this.value;}
}
```

2. Формируем в цикле циклический список:

   Set circleCompas = new HashSet<>();
   CheckPoint last;
   CheckPoint everFirst;
   for(int grad = 0; grad <= 360; grad += 15){
     CheckPoint node = new CheckPoint(grad);
     if(!circleCompas.isEmpty()){
       node.setLeft(last);
       last.setRight(node);
     }
     else{
       everFirst = node;
     }
     last = node;
     circleCompas.add(node);
   }

   everFirst.setLeft(last);
3. Далее - используем эту структуру, например в цикле - считая количество пройденных нод до повторения значения или до достижения значения целевого.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я еще только начал изучать все это и не сталкивался пока со связанным циклическим списком, нодами и т.д. Нужно или что-то другое или разжевать поподробнее Ваш вариант ответа.

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ.